# Enable paging in enable false grid

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

How  to enable paging  when grid is disabled. I have e tried enable false the  grid and enabled the paging

```
 grdMnaualEntryTransactoion.Enabled = false;
 grdMnaualEntryTransactoion.AllowPaging = true;
```

but paging is not working.

Comment: Why do you want to disable the grid? Because paging is a part of grid and when you disable grid every thing will be disabled.

Comment: I need to disable the  check boxes in the grid.

Comment: then disable `check box` only.

Comment: Then i need to use raw data bound event ,I need to disable the check boxes  without using it.

Comment: You can do it using `jquery` too

Comment: It is pointless to provide paging for a disabled grid. The `Enabled` property is inherited from parent to child and the pager is a child of the grid. Imho - it's also a bad user experience.